# Docker Compose Up - Remove Service Name in Log Output

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

Is it possible to remove the service name in the log output of `docker-compose up`?

My logs are currently looking like this:

```
serviceA        | log1
serviceB        | log2
serviceB        | log3
serviceA        | log4
```

But I want them to look like this:

```
log1
log2
log3
log4
```

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging) states, that you can configure the logging for services like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  some-service:
    image: some-service
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
```

But I couldn't find any option to remove the service name from the logs when running `docker-compose up`.

## Update

As proposed by [EchoMike444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4565551), I've tried the following command:

```
docker-compose up --no-color 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^ ]*  | //'
```

with the following docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  consumer:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    command:
      [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "while ( true ) ; do echo $$(date) $$( hostname ) ; sleep $$(( $$RANDOM %4 )) ; done ",
      ]
  ideas:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    restart: always
    command:
      [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "while ( true ) ; do echo $$(date) $$( hostname ) ; sleep $$(( $$RANDOM %4 )) ; done ",
      ]
```

The output looks like this

```
ideas_1     | Sun Oct 20 05:56:23 UTC 2019 99295bdcbf2c
ideas_1     | Sun Oct 20 05:56:25 UTC 2019 99295bdcbf2c
Sun Oct 20 05:56:25 UTC 2019 dd45c5900159
ideas_1     | Sun Oct 20 05:56:27 UTC 2019 99295bdcbf2c
ideas_1     | Sun Oct 20 05:56:27 UTC 2019 99295bdcbf2c
Sun Oct 20 05:56:27 UTC 2019 dd45c5900159
Sun Oct 20 05:56:29 UTC 2019 dd45c5900159
ideas_1     | Sun Oct 20 05:56:30 UTC 2019 99295bdcbf2c
```

So it is working for service `consumer`, but not for `ideas`.

Comment: Didn't you use `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: Daemon mode doesn't show logs. But I want to see the logs, just without "service-name      |" at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can not remove the prefix , I did not see a option in the source code .

`docker-compose` is wrote in *python* feel free to patch .

https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/cli/log_printer.py

A workaround will :

```
 docker-compose up --no-color 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *| //'
```

or

```
 docker-compose up -d
 docker-compose logs --no-color -f 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *| //'
```

I tested MacOS and Linux with this very small `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  serviceA:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    command: ["bash","-c","while ( true ) ; do echo $$(date) $$( hostname ) ; sleep $$(( $$RANDOM %4 )) ; done "]
  serviceB:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    restart: always
    command: ["bash","-c","while ( true ) ; do echo $$(date) $$( hostname ) ; sleep $$(( $$RANDOM %4 )) ; done "]
```

Comment: I've updated my question... so it basically partly works :)

Comment: i made a mistake , you need add a `*` , because the number of spaces is variable

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can now, this PR was merged:

https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/7435

ex: `docker-compose up --no-log-prefix`